# Passing optional parameters to my controller.js in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code in my `controller.js` file in AngularJS:

```
app.controller('MetaDetailGroupList', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get(Routing.generate('meta-detail-group-list')).success(function(data) {
            $scope.MetaDetailGroup = data;
            $scope.orderProp = 'name';
            $scope.currPage = 0;
            $scope.pageSize = 10;

            $scope.totalMetaDetailGroup = function() {
                return Math.ceil($scope.MetaDetailGroup.entities.length / $scope.pageSize);
            };

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.MetaDetailGroup.message = "Ocurrieron errores al procesar los datos, por favor vuelva a intentarlo.";
        });
    }]);
```

I use this function to build a list of items, it works fine. Some of those items has `parent >> children` relationship so I need to call the same function once again but this time passing and ID as a optional parameter to get the right childrens so the only change is this line:

```
From: $http.get(Routing.generate('meta-detail-group-list')).success(function(data)

To: $http.get(Routing.generate('meta-detail-group-list' + '/'+id)).success(function(data)
```

How I can do this without write another function just for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you move your $http call to a service and handle the id processing stuff there:

```
app.service('MetaDetailGroupListService',function($http) {
    return {
        metaDetailGroupList : function(_id) {
            var _s = (typeof _id === 'undefined') ?
                'meta-detail-group-list' :
                'meta-detail-group-list' + '/' + _id;
            return $http.get(Routing.generate(_s));
        }
    }
});

app.controller('MetaDetailGroupList', ['$scope', 'MetaDetailGroupListService',
function($scope, MetaDetailGroupListService) {
    MetaDetailGroupListService.metaDetailGroupList(id).success(function(data) {
        $scope.MetaDetailGroup = data;
        $scope.orderProp = 'name';
        $scope.currPage = 0;
        $scope.pageSize = 10;

        $scope.totalMetaDetailGroup = function() {
            return Math.ceil($scope.MetaDetailGroup.entities.length / $scope.pageSize);
        };

    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.MetaDetailGroup.message = "Ocurrieron errores al procesar los datos, por favor vuelva a intentarlo.";
    });
}]);
```